# DiscordJS V14. Is there a nice way to have Playingstatus switch randomly AND have them be of different types?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an array of Playingstatuses like this:

```
let statuses=[
'Status 1',
'Status 2',
//and so on
```

My bot switches randomly between these like this:

```
let statuswatching = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]

setInterval(function(){
            client.user.setPresence({
                activities: [{ name: statuswatching, type: ActivityType.Watching }],
                status: 'online',
            });
        }, 180000)
```

It works perfectly fine like this and switches the Statustext every 3 minutes, but its type is always 'watching' which is okay for the texts I have set up. But I have ideas for more statuses which should start with 'playing', 'listening' and so on.

I know I can switch the type by changing "ActivityType.Watching" to something else, but that would change it for all of the texts, not just the ones that should have it.

I tried changing up the array to this:

```
let statuses=[

'{ name: `Status1`, type: ActivityType.Watching }',
'{ name: `Status2`, type: ActivityType.Playing }',

let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]

// And then replace the code to this:

setInterval(function(){
            client.user.setPresence({
                activities: [status],
                status: 'online',
            });
        }, 180000)
```

I know there are probably 100 reasons why this did not work, but I'm still fairly new to NodeJS and DiscordJS V14

Of course I also tried googling, but there was nothing useful to be found, especially since googling for DiscordJS related questions becomes harder with every version they release.

Comment: Move `let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]` inside the `setInterval` callback, above `client.user.setPresence` so it generated a new status randomly every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `string` not an `object`. Your code also has a bunch of syntax errors.

The correct code to change your activity name & status would be:

```js
let statuses = [
    {
        name: `Status1`,
        type: ActivityType.Watching
    },
    {
        name: `Status2`,
        type: ActivityType.Playing
    }
];
setInterval(function() {
    let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
    client.user.setPresence({
        activities: [status],
        status: 'online',
    });
}, 180000)
```